# Do big-box stores sell inferior versions of plumbing fixtures?

Tags: plumbing

Do big-box stores such as the Home Depot and Lowe's carry plumbing fixtures that have the same name and appearance as at other stores, but with lower quality to keep the price low?

Comment: While this information is useful, I'm not sure this type of question is a good  fit for the site.

Comment: Volume Discount. Manufacturers have pricing tiers based on how much you buy. Nationwide buyers have huge volume as opposed to your hometown fixture shop who is buying for your town and surrounding area.

Comment: Yes, they often do.

Answer (score 4):

I phoned Kohler to ask them this exact question. The answer, at least for Kohler, is that if the part number is exactly the same, the product is exactly the same. However, some parts, sold only at the Home Depot and Lowe's, have an "R" prefix on the part number. This stands for "retail" and can signify that cheaper parts have been used to reduce cost; for example some metal parts may have been replaced with plastic parts.

Comment: This is absolutely true.  Try buying a shower head from a big box that doesn't have a metal-lookalike lock nut for under $100.  Good luck finding on the package that this plastic made to look like metal.  Don't think I have ever bought direct from manufacturer or plumbing wharehouse and ever came across crap like this.  There are just certain things you learn to love and hate about each big box and big boxes in general.

Answer (score 0):

Big box stores -- and other stores, for that matter -- generally offer both "builder quality" (ie, cheaply-made stuff that looks good but isn't as durable) and higher-quality goods, in everything from locks to appliances to you-name-it. Often both are available from the same manufacturer, so the brand name and style alone aren't enough to tell them apart.

Your choices are to learn a bit about the product lines and what clues are on the packaging (for example, the difference between lock grades), to get a pro to advise you, to assume that the cheapest version is cheap for a reason, or to gamble. Gambling is sometimes a perfectly reasonable choice, for components that you'll be putting less wear on or that you're willing to accept some annoyances with; landlords do that all the time with appliances since they won't be the ones paying the energy bills.